# Opening a popup inside a WPF tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to open a popup window inside a TabControl in WPF, however for some reason its not working yet.

I have the following:-

```
    <Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Header1">
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Header2">
        </TabItem>
        <StackPanel Name="MyPanel">
            <Popup  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Name="MyToolTip" StaysOpen="True" AllowsTransparency="False"  />
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Azure" Margin="0,0,378.8,0" >
                <StackPanel Margin="30"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="My Popup "/>
                    <TextBlock  x:Name="MyFirstPopupTextBlock" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

and in the .cs I have the following:-

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Show_Popup();
    }

    private void Show_Popup()
    {
        MyToolTip.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: What are you tring to do, Show the StackPanel as a ToolTip?

Comment: And you want this popup in a `StackPanel` as a `TabItem`? or do you want it to appear on all TabItems?

Comment: I want it to appear on all tab Items, sort of independently of the Tab Item I am on

Comment: How will it be opened, or do you just want to use it as a ToolTip, openes when mouse is over?

Comment: I want it opened like a popup.  I want to just call the method and a popup is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to appear on all `TabItems`, you will probably want to add it to the `Grid`, not the `TabControl`, this way it will aways be ontop of the `TabControl` when opened.

```
 <Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Header1" />
        <TabItem Header="Header2" />
    </TabControl>
    <Popup Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Name="MyToolTip" StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="True" Placement="Center" PlacementTarget="{Binding}" AllowsTransparency="False"  >
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Azure"  >
            <StackPanel Margin="30"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="My Popup "/>
                <TextBlock  x:Name="MyFirstPopupTextBlock" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]